# WPF clickable dynamic TextBlock MVVM

Tags: wpf, templates, mvvm, relaycommand

I have a task to create a clickable element inside a ListView, which is created by Bindings. I looked at the guides, used RelayCommand, it did not work. Please tell me the solution to the problem, why it does not work.

**RelayCommand**

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null) { }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute)); _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute?.Invoke(parameter) ?? true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }
    public void Execute(object parameter) { _execute(parameter); }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
    public class HomeViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private readonly CoinCapHandler _coinCapHandler;
        public List<Coin> Coins { get; set; } = new List<Coin>();
        public List<Coin> AllCoins { get; set; } = new List<Coin>();

        public RelayCommand IsCheckedCommand { get; set; }

        public ICommand OpenWindowCommand { get; }


        private string? _searchText = "";
        public string SearchText
        {
            get => _searchText;
            set
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    _searchText = value.ToString();
                    ActiveFilter();
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SearchText));
                }
            }
        }

        private string _selectedFilter = "By Name";
        public string SelectedFilter
        {
            get => _selectedFilter;
            set
            {
                _selectedFilter = value.ToString();
                ActiveFilter();
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedFilter));
            }
        }

        public HomeViewModel()
        {
            _coinCapHandler = new CoinCapHandler();

            IsCheckedCommand = new RelayCommand(m => IsCheckedCommandExecute());

            LoadCoinsAsync();

            //OpenWindowCommand = new RelayCommand(OpenWindow);
        }
        private void IsCheckedCommandExecute()
        {
            //OnPropertyChanged(nameof());
        }

        private async void LoadCoinsAsync()
        {
            AllCoins = await _coinCapHandler.GetAllCoinsAsync();
            Coins = await _coinCapHandler.GetAllCoinsAsync();
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Coins));
        }

        private async void ActiveFilter()
        {
            if (_selectedFilter == "System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: By Name")
            {
                Coins = new(AllCoins.Where(coin =>
                    coin.Name.Contains(_searchText)));
            }
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Coins));
        }
    }
```

**XAML**

```
<Grid Margin="30 10 30 20" Grid.Row="2">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Coins}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" >
                        <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                            <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick" Command="{Binding IsCheckedCommandExecute}" />
                        </TextBlock.InputBindings>
                    </TextBlock>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView >
                <GridViewColumn Header="Rank">
                    <GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                        <Binding Path="Rank" StringFormat="{}{0:D}"/>
                    </GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name">
                    <GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                        <Binding Path="Name"/>
                    </GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Symbol">
                    <GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                        <Binding Path="Symbol"/>
                    </GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Price">
                    <GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                        <Binding Path="Price" StringFormat="{}{0:C}"/>
                    </GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Change">
                    <GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                        <Binding Path="ChangePercent" StringFormat="{}{0:P}"/>
                    </GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Market Cap">
                    <GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                        <Binding Path="MarketCapUsd" StringFormat="{}{0:N}"/>
                    </GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

I try to use RelayCommand class from guides. But when the element is clicked, the method is not executed.

Comment: You would need a relativesource binding to get to that command. You could put your textblock inside a button which has command and command parameter properties react to clicking.  There are other options like you could bind selected item to a property and act in the setter. Whichever you choose I suggest you use the mvvm community toolkit which saves a lot of boiler plate code and has some really great functionality.